# Grouping of identical objects into groups with equal no. of objects in them

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have been told that when grouping $6$ identical objects into $3$ groups containing same no. of objects we have to divide $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$ by $3!$. I follow up to how we got $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$.  I want to know why we have to divide by $3!$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: ".... have been told..." By whom ? Is it by a book or by a person ? If it is from a book, what is the **exact** wording ?

Comment: It has been told by a person that we divide by 3! because there are three identical groups.

Comment: That is a short explanation of the answer.  If you want to convince yourself, try a smaller example of $4$ objects into $2$ groups of $2$: are there three or six ways?  Or $3$ objects into $3$ groups of $1$: is there one or three ways?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid either the question is wrong, and if not, the answer is wrong!

As it reads, you are grouping **identical** objects into equal groups, and if you think about it, there is just one way !

Eg if the objects are $AAAAAA$, you divide into $AA|AA|AA$

Probably the question you had in mind was grouping **distinct** (I prefer the term *labeled*) objects into equal groups.

Now, if the groups are also distinct (labeled), the answer would just be $\frac{6!}{2!2!2!}$, like if you form teams of $2$ from $6$ people to form team Tigers, Lions and Panthers

The division by $3!$ is necessary only if the teams are unlabeled, because $AB|CD|EF$ for instance is the same as, say,  $CD|EF|AB$

Comment: You hit the spot